# php: how to split a string by an array of characters?

Tags: php, string, split, explode, preg-split

I would like to split a string by an array of characters, how would I do that? I notice [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) takes a string input not an array.

For example, here is my array:

`$splitting_strings = array(".", ";", "-", "and", "for");`

`$text = "What a great day, and I love it. Who knows; maybe I will go.";`

```
$result = array (
0 => "What a great day",
1 => "I love it",
2 =>  "Who knows",
3 => "maybe I will go");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) the following:

```
$regex = '/(' . implode('|', $splitting_strings) . ')/';
```

You will need to escape any special regex characters such as `.`. So you should end up with something like this instead:

```
// run through each element in the array escaping any
// special regex chars
$splitting_strings = array_map(function($string) {
                                   return preg_quote($string);
                               }, $splitting_strings);

$regex = '/(' . implode('|', $splitting_strings) . ')/';
$final_array = preg_split($regex, $splitting_strings);
```

The output of `$final_array` after all this is:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "What a great day, "
  [1]=>
  string(10) " I love it"
  [2]=>
  string(10) " Who knows"
  [3]=>
  string(16) " maybe I will go"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it should be round brackets no? [and] also matches "dna", since square brackets are for character classes, while round brackets are for grouping as I understand.

Comment: Yes it should be () instead of []

Comment: I have updated this, but it means you will now need to escape regex symbols such as `.` to stop it from splitting on everything! :)

Comment: @giorgio79 I had updated the answer with a simple a escaping routine.